# Flutter bottom sheet modal effect

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve a similar design to the bottom sheet used on the Samsung Notes app:

[image]

I'm able to add the rounded corners, but I'm unable to make the system navigation bar at the bottom transparent. I think there is also a slight margin between the bottom sheet and the system navigation bar which I'm unable to achieve.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

I've been made aware of the `SystemChrome` class which I think is supposed to help with this, but I haven't had any luck yet:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you are running that last piece of code, But it works for me. I put the following code being called in a button and I didn't even need to use a setState:

```
class SystemColorChangeIssue extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeNamed = '/news-screen-detail';

  @override
  _SystemColorChangeIssueState createState() => _SystemColorChangeIssueState();
}

class _SystemColorChangeIssueState extends State<SystemColorChangeIssue> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () => changeSystemColor(Colors.red),
            child: Text('Red'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () => changeSystemColor(Colors.blue),
            child: Text('Blue'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () => changeSystemColor(Colors.transparent),
            child: Text('Transparent'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.pink,
            onPressed: () => showModal(context),
            child: Text('Show modal and show pink'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeSystemColor(Color color){
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: color,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
  }

  void showModal(context){
    changeSystemColor(Colors.pink);
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          height: 200,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Modal'),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

You should be able to run the same code on trigger to show your modal.

Comment: could you give a more complete code example? I've tried calling it before and after i call `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: I've modified my answer with a more complete code example.

Comment: I've added a modal now as well, the last button. It will show a modal and change the System color.

Comment: I created a new flutter project with your code and it does colour the bottom bar, but I stated in my question that I'm trying to make it transparent, as shown in the first picture.

Comment: Just change one of the colours to transparent. It will show whatever colour is the background of your app.

Comment: I've changed one of the buttons to change it to transparent.

Comment: So you're saying I also need to alter the background colour of my app to some dark shade, just like in the first image?? Atm when I set it to transparent it becomes white which I assume is the background colour under the bottom bar.

Comment: Very likely. The transparency will always be relative. You would probably benefit from simply setting it to a grey that matches the darkening of the background that the Modal does automatically.

Comment: Could you tell me exactly which background property I need to set? Still unable to get it working :/

Comment: What do you mean background property? You don't change the background color. You set the system ui color with the method to a grey that matches the background color that shows up when you show the modal.